# Standard error of ratio of predicted probabilities

Tags: r, statistics, prediction, glm

I have a data set with a continuous independent variable X and a categorical dependent variable Y with three categories (a, b, and c). I have fitted a multinomial logit model to the data. In addition to the predicted probability of each outcome as a function of X, I am interested in the probability of c conditional on b or c (i.e, not a).

I can easily extract the predicted probabilities from the model and their standard errors. The predicted probability of c divided by the sum of predicted probabilities of b or c is also straightforward. But I can't work out how to calculate the standard error of this last quantity.

MWE here:

```
# load packages
require(ggplot2)
require(nnet)
require(effects)
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

# simulate data with categorical dependent variable
simdat<-data.frame(x=1:10,
                   y=c("a","a","a","b","a","b","c","b","a","c"))

# fit multinomial logit model
mm1<-multinom(y~x,data=simdat)

# get predicted probabilities of each outcome across the range of x
preds<-effect("x",mm1,xlevels=list(x=1:10),se=T) 

# collect predicted probs and prediction se's in data frame
predsdf<-gather(as_data_frame(preds$prob),"probcat","prob") %>% 
  bind_cols(gather(as_data_frame(preds$se.prob),"secat","se")) %>% 
  mutate(x=rep(1:10,3))

# calculate probability of c conditional on b or c (i.e., not a)
predsdf<-predsdf %>% 
  bind_rows(.,data_frame(probcat="prob.c / (prob.b + prob.c)",
                         prob=.$prob[21:30]/(.$prob[11:20]+.$prob[21:30]),
                         secat="prob.c / (prob.b + prob.c)",
                         se=NA, # how to calculate this standard error?
                         x=1:10))

# plot predicted probs and se's across range of x
ggplot(predsdf,aes(x=x,y=prob,ymin=prob-1*se,ymax=prob+1*se,group=probcat,color=probcat)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(alpha=.2) +
  theme_bw()
```

That last line gives this plot:

[image: predicted probabilities of each category]

What I'm looking for is the standard error for the purple line in the plot. Intuitively it should be larger than the standard errors for the predictions of b and c, but I can't work out how to calculate it.

Comment: A confidence interval for a _probability_ can't go below zero.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The plot above is from the simulation data, and it's not an issue in my actual data, but certainly correct.